# Adding Unified Label to outgoing Outlook email via Powershell script

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office-automation, microsoft-information-protection

I have a function that goes into a larger Powershell script.  This function constructs and sends an email using Outlook.  I'm using Outlook instead of Send-MailMessage or straight to SMTP because I need to include the Microsoft Unified Label that my organization has implemented (Public, Private, etc).

From what I can piece together from various online sources it should be something like ths:

```
Function outlookSend {
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application -Verbose:$false
    $message = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $message.GetInspector.Activate()
    $message.To = $recipient
    $message.Subject = $subject
    $message.HtmlBody = $body
    $message.UserProperties.Add("MSIP_Label_11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555_Enabled", olText, True)
    $message.Send()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outlook) | Out-Null
}
```

`MSIP_Label_11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555_Enabled` including the GUID of the label that I want to use.  When I run this I get the error:

```
Exception setting "Add": Cannot convert the "olText" value of type "string" to type "Object".
At C:\scripts\slaMail.ps1:211 char:5
+     $emailMessage.UserProperties.Add("MSIP_Label_3a2fed65-62e7-46ea-a ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I then converted "olText" to an object using:

```
$olText = ('olText' | ConvertFrom-String)
```

and using this line:

```
$message.UserProperties.Add("MSIP_Label_11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555_Enabled", $olText)
```

But, that gave me the following error:

```
A field name cannot contain the following characters: [, ], _, and #.
At C:\scripts\slaMail.ps1:211 char:5
+     $emailMessage.UserProperties.Add("MSIP_Label_3a2fed65-62e7-46ea-a ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I did try escaping the "_" and even making it into a variable like I did with olText, but neither worked.  I'm not sure I'm on the right track here or going the wrong direction.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the property name and its value. What you are trying to add as a property should be used as a property value. The last error message clearly indicate that:

```
A field name cannot contain the following characters: [, ], _, and #.
```

For example, the following code can be used instead:

```
propertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F", yourPropertyText);
```

You can use the `UserProperty.Value` property to set a property value after adding it.

You also can use the [SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) method instead as shown in my sample code above, it sets the property specified by `SchemaName` to the value specified by `Value`. To set for the first time a property created by the `UserProperties.Add` method, use the `UserProperty.Value` property instead of the `SetProperties` or `SetProperty` method of the `PropertyAccessor` object.

```
propertyAccessor.SetProperty myProp, myValue
```

If the property does not exist and the `SchemaName` contains a valid property specifier, then `SetProperty` creates the property and assigns the value specified by Value. If the property does exist and `SchemaName` is valid, then `SetProperty` assigns the property with the value specified by `Value`.

The name of the property is a string with the maximum length of 64 characters. The characters, '[', ']', '_' and '#', are not permitted in the name.